# Как выровнять блок неизвестной высоты по центру вертикали?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

[Условия задачи](http://jsfiddle.net/zKJ2N/). 
Блок с текстом должен находиться справа от фотографии и выравниваться по центру вертикали. При этом его высота неизвестна (зависит от контента).

Comment: Что пробовали?

Comment: @neoascetic, ну судя по фидлу многое :) Например, использование `display: table-cell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, что-то вроде такого : [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/shanhaichik/PLgrw/)

```
#outer{width:100%; height:100%;}        
#outer div{
        border: 1px solid black;            
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle; 
        position:relative; 
        height:100%;
        width:200px;
    }
    #img {
       width:210px!important; 
  }
```

​С шириной, точнее ее размерами я думаю что сами можете поэкспериментировать.

Comment: Спасибо, это работает

Answer (score 1):

В такой разметке, на сколько я понимаю, никак. Попробуй сделать таблицу, в левой ячейке выводи фотку, в правой текст. Попытка выровнять текст по вертикали должна быть успешной.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но хотелось бы обойтись без таблиц.

Answer (score 1):

[С использованием JS](http://jsfiddle.net/PxHZa/1/), но т.к. у вас про ограничения ничего не написано, то вот так.

Comment: Лучше после `window.load`. И вместо `height` можно `margin-top: (высота изображения - высота текста)/2`. А если юзают less на стороне клиента (сомневаюсь, конечно), то еще проще

Comment: Насчёт onload согласен, но это просто набросок, чтобы показать. А в остальном я думаю главное сама мысль понятна.
PS картинку заменил, потому что та грузилась медленно)